# Clarification of definitions of function being a contraction in $L_{p}$ space

Tags: probability-theory, definition, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation

This question arose from Durrett Theorem 4.1.4, as follows:

> Conditional expectation is a contraction in $L^{p}$ space for $p\geq 1$.

This question has been addressed here: [Contraction Property of Conditional Expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441648/contraction-property-of-conditional-expectation), and it seems that a conditional expectation being a contraction in $L_{p}$ means that it satisfies $$\|\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}))\|_{p}\leq\|X\|_{p}.$$ but this definition seems not working in other cases. For instance, what it means by a random variable being a contraction in $L_{p}$?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(operator_theory), a bounded operator $T:X\longrightarrow Y$ between normed linear spaces $X$ and $Y$ means it satisfies $\|T\|_{Y}\leq 1$. So a random variable $X\in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ being a contraction means it satisfies $\|X\|_{p}\leq 1$?

But from here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping it seems that a map being contraction has another meaning.

Are these definitions equivalent or sort of related to each other or they are totally independent among each other?

The word **contraction** appears only once in Durrett, which is in this theorem. So I do need a general clarification of the definition of "contraction"

Please point it out if my question is not clear. Thank you so much!

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to "kimchi lover", now it is really clear. I edit this post to simply prove this statement and clarify everything for further readers.

> **[Contraction].** Given two normed linear space $V$ and $W$, a linear map $T:V\longrightarrow W$ is continuous if and only if there exists a real number $c$ such that $$\|T(v)\|_{W}\leq c\|v\|_{V},\ \text{for all}v\ \in V.$$
>
> Then we define the operator norm of $T$ as $$\|T\|_{op}:=\inf\{c\geq 0:\|T(v)\|_{W}\leq c\|v\|_{V}\ \text{for all}v\ \in V\}.$$
>
> An operator is said to be a contraction if $\|T\|_{op}\leq 1$.
>
> ---
>
> **[Refined Statement].** The operator of obtaining conditional expectation is a contraction in $L_{p}$ for $p\geq 1$

*Proof:* Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{0},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{F}_{0}$ a $\sigma-$algebra, we show that the operator $$T:L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\longrightarrow L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\ \text{defined by}$$ $$X\mapsto\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}),$$ is a contraction.

Firstly, the absolute value function $|\ \cdot\ |^{p}$ is convex for $p\geq 1$. Therefore, by Jensen we have $$\Big|\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})\Big|^{p}\leq\mathbb{E}(|X|^{p}|\mathcal{F}),$$ so taking expectation we have $$\mathbb{E}\Big|\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})\Big|^{p}\leq\mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}(|X|^{p}|\mathcal{F})\Big).$$

Now, $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra (in fact a sub-$\sigma-$algebra), so $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$, then by the second criterion of conditional probability, we have $$\mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}(|X|^{p}|\mathcal{F})\Big)=\mathbb{E}|X|^{p}.$$

These together imply that $$\|\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})\|_{p}\leq\|X\|_{p},$$ which is saying that for all $X\in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, $$\|T(X)\|_{p}\leq\|X\|_{p}.$$

Therefore, the operator norm of $T$, being the infimum, must be $\leq 1$. Thus, $T$ is a contraction.

Comment: It's not random variables that are contractions, but the operation of obtaining conditional expectations that is a contraction.  That is, the map $c_{\mathcal F}$ is a contraction, where $c_{\mathcal F}: X\mapsto E[X|\mathcal F]$.

Comment: @kimchilover so how to connect with the desired result with the norm of operator being $\leq 1$?

Comment: @kimchilover oh! okay, so it is operator norm. okay, so if I have the desired inequality, then the inf is $1$.

Comment: Good.  In the meantime I composed an answer saying what you just said.

Comment: @kimchilover oh! one correction of my comment, the inf is $\leq 1$, and thus enough to conclude. (Otherwise I prove the operator norm is exactly $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal F$ is a sub-algebra of $\sigma$.  Then the operator  $c_{\mathcal F}:L^p(\Omega,\sigma,P)\to L^p(\Omega,\sigma,P)$ given by $c_{\mathcal F}:X\mapsto E[X|\mathcal F]$ is a contraction in the usual sense.

Jensen's inequality shows $\|X\|_p \le \|c_{\mathcal F} X\|_p$, so the operator norm of $c_{\mathcal F}$ is $\le1$.  But for $\mathcal F$-measurable rvs $X$ (including constant rvs) one has $c_{\mathcal F} X=X$, so the operator norm of $c_{\mathcal F}$is $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!